# File handling in cloud micro service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am building an email micro service that is responsible for sending emails , now to be able to handle mail attachment I have two options

1. Save file to a shared repository
2. Embed the file in the stream message

What is the best approach for this knowing that email attachment might be up to 5 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible to claim check the attachment (solution 1), I would recommend that.

Comment: for solution 1 i was thinking in having NFS shared location , but if NFS Server went down then all services are down . Any suggested method that can be HA ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to choose a store that doesn't become a single point of failure - that is not an application concern. You may consider HDFS if that's an option for you (e.g. you're in the Hadoop world).

Comment: Thanks for the response , i think i am going to use GlusterFS i found it easier for my case

Comment: Nice - feel free to share any example you have.